# Trouble while linking to a Brand with itemref

Tags: microdata, rich-snippets, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm trying to link a `Brand` to a `Product` with the following code:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="p2000">
...
   <meta itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand" itemref="v1437"/>
...
</div>
```

The `Brand` is already defined on the same web page above, inside an independant block:

```
<h1 itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand" id="v1437">
   <span itemprop="name">MyBrand</span>
   <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.example.com/MyBrand"/>
   <meta itemprop="logo" content="http://www.example.com/MyBrand/logo.png"/>
</h1>
```

The validator can't find the `name` property inside the linked `Brand` object

[image: Can't find 'name']

The link between a `Brand` and a `Person` seems to be working, but the `Person` object is not displaying the `Brand`'s name:

[image: Not displaying 'name']

I can use the `itemref` and `id` attributes on other objects. I can link `Offer`s to `Product`s and `Offer`s to `Person`s using the same way.

Is this a bug from the validator?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32564474/1591669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemref` does not work like that.

You have to add the `itemref` attribute to the element you want to apply a property to, and this property has to be defined on an element with the matching ID.

So your example should be:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="v1437">
</div>

<h1 itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand" id="v1437">
   <span itemprop="name">MyBrand</span>
   <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/MyBrand"/>
   <link itemprop="logo" href="http://www.example.com/MyBrand/logo.png"/>
</h1>
```

(I changed two `meta` elements to `link` elements, which is [required if the value is a URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669).)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's perfectly working but I would like to link the Brand to a Product and to an AggregateRating at the same time. I can't put both itemprop="brand" and itemprop="itemReviewed". Isn't there another way for that except duplicating the Brand item ?

Comment: Also, if I set an itemprop="WebPage" inside the body element, it tells me that it doesn't recognize the "brand" attribute.

Comment: New question : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/85033/55879

Comment: @AxelIsouard: Yeah, Microdata formally doesn’t allow to use properties that are not defined for a type (while RDFa and JSON-LD don’t disallow this), so you can’t use `brand` and `itemReviewed` together in Microdata -- And yes, if using `itemref`, you have to take care not to have this element as a child of a parent item (like `WebPage`) to which it doesn’t belong. It’s not always easy, and sometimes impossible, to achieve what you want with Microdata.

Answer (score 0):

i guess , that you get different Id's: in case of `<meta itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand" itemref="v1437"/>` is it **v1437**, in case of `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"></div>` it will be **p1437**: thats why they aren't match and testing tool can't recognize them correctly

Comment: I have to name the Brand and Product differently, since I can't put two different elements with the same id. If they had the same id, the validator wouldn't recognize which one I would like to refer to.