# Linking a Product and an AggregateRating to a Brand (itemref)

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org

I have a `Brand` and a `Product`, I am associating the `Product` to the `Brand` like this:

```
<h1 itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand" id="v1437">
   <span itemprop="name">MyBrand</span>
   <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/MyBrand"/>
   <link itemprop="logo" href="http://www.example.com/MyBrand/logo.png"/>
</h1>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="v1437">
   <span itemprop="name">MyProduct</span>
</div>
```

I would like to create an `AggregateRating` associated to the `Brand`, like the following:

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope
     itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"
     itemref="v1437">
  <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.24"/>
  <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="17"/>
</div>
```

The `AggregateRating` needs an `itemReviewed` field, pointing to the `Brand`, I can add an `itemReviewed` attribute inside my `Brand`:

```
<h1 itemprop="brand itemReviewed" itemscope 
    itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand" id="v1437">
```

But the validator displays some conflicts:

> [image: 1 error for Product, 1 error for AggregateRating]

Is there another way to achieve this without having to duplicate the `Brand`?

EDIT: Referring to Evgeniy's answer, I can't embed an item into another, `itemref` seems to be the only option available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do the job, and is errorfree validated:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"
     itemref="v1437">
<span itemprop="name">MyProduct</span>
</div>

<div itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand"
     id="v1437" itemref="p1437">
<h1 itemprop="name">MyBrand</h1>
<link itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/MyBrand"/>
<link itemprop="logo" href="http://www.example.com/MyBrand/logo.png"/>
</div>

<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"
     id="p1437">
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.24"/>
<meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="17"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working indeed. However, I must admit that I wasn't explicit enough, I forgot to tell that I can't embed an item into another, `itemref` is the only option available afaik.

Comment: i thought firstly about embedding/nesting of items one into another, like product->brand->aggregateRating. It works like a charm too. But i f you can't nest them because of layout issues, then itemref does the rest.

Comment: A good way to achieve this was indeed organizing items differently. Thanks again !